# Piramide de numeros en Javascript sin HTML

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabado en este ejercicio intente hacerlo con un **ciclo for dentro de otro** pero no se me ocurre la manera de lograr que se vayan acumulando los valores y haciendo el salto de linea. Aca le dejo el ejercicio:

Crear un script que genere una pirámide como el ejemplo con los números del 1 al

número que ingrese el usuario (no puede ser mayor de 10, realizar la validación):

1

12

123

1234

12345

123456

Aca les dejo hasta donde hice:

```javascript
    function piramide(valor){
       
        if( valor <= 10){
            for(let i = 1 ; i <= valor; i++){
                
                for(let x = 0; x <= i ; x++){
      
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu algoritmo debería ser algo así:

```js
function printPiramid(number){
  for( let i = 1; i <= number; i++){
    let string = ''
    for( let h = 1; h <= i; h++)  string += h
    console.log(string)
  }
}

printPiramid(10)
```

Me ayudo de un string auxiliar que concatene los valores del for interior, y al terminar su iteración imprima por consola el resultado.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto mi consulta porque no abriste corchetes en el segundo for y pusiste en la misma linea el string += h

Comment: si un bloque como un if, un for un while etc solo tiene una línea de código dentro, puedes quitar las llaves y poner esa única línea al lado de dicho bloque. Pero perfectamente puede hacerse con llaves.

Answer (score 2):

A pesar de que la pregunta ya tiene una respuesta super-buena, decidí agregar esta, ya que evita el uso de dos `for`.

```js
function creaPiramide( numero ) {
    let palabra = "";
    for( let i = 1; i <= numero; i++ ) {
        palabra += i;
        console.log( palabra )
    }
}

// Como se ve, solo hace falta un `for` e ir concatenado los nuevos números
// con el acumulado de ellos.  
// No me conformé con eso, y quise ir un paso más allá, y hacer una pirámide
// simétrica... y con un solo `for`.    

function creaPiramideSimetrica( numero ) {
    let espacios = Math.floor( numero / 2 );    

    var separa = Array( espacios ).fill( " " );
    let sepa = separa.join();
    let sep = sepa.replaceAll( ",", "" );  
  
    let palabra = "1";
    console.log( sep + palabra );

    for( let i = 2; i <= numero; i += 2 ) {
        sep = sep.replace( " ", "" );
        palabra += i + "" + ( i  + 1 );
        console.log( sep + palabra );
    }
}

creaPiramide( 9 );
creaPiramideSimetrica( 9 );
```

El resultado es bastante complicado, debido a la auto-exigencia de usar un solo `for`.
Requisitos, el número ingresado tiene que ser impar y menor que "10" (sino se rompe la estética).
Empezamos dividiendo el número por "2", y mediante el método `floor` de la clase `Math`, obtenemos el entero inmediato inferior, que nos indica la cantidad de espacios a dejar antes de imprimir el número correspondiente.
Luego, con el método `Array`, creamos un `array` de un tamaño determinado, lo llenamos de " " con el método `fill`.
Después creamos una cadena, usando el método `join`, y seguido usamos `replaceAll` para quitar todas las comas.
La impresión de la primer linea la hacemos fuera del `for`.
Dentro del `for`, (que "salta" dos posiciones por iteración), "acortamos" **`palabra`** usando `replace`, que solo afecta a la primer aparición de un determinado patrón.
Luego concatenamos **`palabra`** con los dos próximos números.
Solo nos resta imprimir el separador seguido da los números.

Y si en vez de un `for`...

```js
function creaPiramide( numero, palabra, i ) {
    console.log( palabra += i );
    if( i < numero ) {
        creaPiramide( numero, palabra, i + 1 );
    }
}  

function creaPiramideSimetrica( palabra, numero, i ) {
    let espacios = Math.floor( numero / 2 );
    let separador = creaSeparador( "", espacios );
    console.log( separador + palabra );
    if( 1 < numero ) {
        palabra += i + "" + ( i + 1 );
        creaPiramideSimetrica( palabra, numero -2, i +2 )
    }
}

function creaSeparador( palabra, espacios ) {
   if( palabra.length == espacios ) {
       return palabra;
   }
   return creaSeparador( palabra += " ", espacios );
}   

creaPiramide( 9, "", 1 );
creaPiramideSimetrica( "1", 9, 2 );
```

El primero de los métodos no puede ser más simple, recibe como parámetros, el número más grande a imprimir, una cadena vacia, y un "1", que será agregado la cadena que se imprime.
El `if` comprueba si **`i`** es menor que el número final, si lo es, llama a **`crearPiramide`** (recursión), pasandole el número maximo, la palabra modificada, asi como **`i`** aumentado en "1", si no es menor, se sale e la función.

Mañana explico el último método...

Bueno hoy es mañana.. pero el mañana de ayer... mejor explico el código.

La función **`creaPiramideSimetrica`**, recibe como parámetros, una cadena con la primer letra a imprimir, el mayor de los numeros a imprimir, y el número "2", que será el segundo número impreso y base de los siguientes.
Instanciamos **`espacios`** de la misma forma que el ejemplo anterior.
A **`separador`** la instanciamos con la devolución de **`creaSeparador`**, que recibe una cadena vacia, y la cantidad de espacios que se deben dejar entre el margen y el número.
Si la cadena recibida es mas corta que el espacio a generar, se vuelve a llamar (recursión) agregando a la palabra un espacio, hasta crear el separador adecuado y retornarlo.
Seguido a esto imprimimos la cima de la pirámide.
En el `if`, que **`numero`** sea mayor que "1", si lo es, agregamos a la cadena el valor de **`i`** y el valor de **`i`** mas "1", y luego se llama a si misma con los nuevos valores de las variables, hasta que **`numero`** sea igual a "1", que hace finalizar la función.